# Azure Windows 8 Authentication

Tags: c#, windows, azure

How can I use authentication for azure in one page then have access to the database in other pages of the application. Facebook and microsoft login works fine if everything is one the same page but id like to authenticate in the menu screen then pass the items over to the viewing page. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [How to Authenticate Web Users with Windows Azure Access Control Service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/access-control/) - gives you a complete walk-through.  There is also a complete demo/wlk0through here - [Windows Azure Authenticaction](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/fall-2012-update/windows-azure-authentication)